# Bulk insert .txt file in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, bulkinsert

I'm trying to import a .txt file into Advanced Query Tool (the SQL client I use). So far, I have:

```
CREATE TABLE #tb_test
(
id INTEGER,
name varchar(10),
dob date,
city char(20),
state char(20),
zip integer
);

insert into #tb_test
values
(1,'TEST','2015-01-01','TEST','TEST',11111)
;

bulk insert #tb_test
from 'h:\tbdata.txt'
    with
    (
    fieldterminator = '\t',
    rowterminator = '\n'
    );
```

I receive an error message saying there's a syntax error on line 1. Am I missing a database from which #tb_test comes (like db.#tb_test)?

Here's a line from the tbdata.txt file:

```
2,'TEST2','2012-01-01','TEST','TEST',21111
```

Comment: Could you put sample lines from your `h:\tbdata.txt` file?

Comment: Your SQL Syntax works! I think the error is in  `h:\tbdata.txt`   maybe wrong delimiters or blanks, whitespaces,...!?

Comment: Try replacing "integer" with "int".

Comment: can you post the exact error ? the only error seems to be this script can appear if the file is wrong or its execute twice...

Comment: The exact error message: "Error during Prepare. 37000(-131)[Sybase][ODBC Driver][Sybase IQ]Syntax error near 'bulk' on line 1 (0.02 secs)."

Comment: I know the syntax is right... Does #tb_test need to be part of another schema or database aggregation in order for this to work? I'm coming from a SAS background, where importing files is just proc import ....

Answer (score 0):

I was curious with this question and I found the following solution:

Your data is comma separated but you are trying to split by TAB
two options: change the file data to be TAB separated **or** change the `fieldterminator = '\t'` to `fieldterminator = ','`

The DATE format has issues when loading directly from a file, my best solution is to change the temp field **dob** to type VARCHAR(20) and then, when passing to the final display/data storage convert to DATE.

Here is the corrected code:

```
CREATE TABLE #tb_test
(
id INTEGER,
name varchar(10),
dob varchar(20),
city char(20),
state char(20),
zip integer
);

insert into #tb_test
values
(1,'TEST','2015-01-01','TEST','TEST',11111)
;

bulk insert #tb_test
from 'h:\tbdata.txt'
    with
    (
    fieldterminator = ',',
    rowterminator = '\n'
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm sure this works in SQL Server; however, I'm using a Sybase IQ tool.

Comment: @GBR24 Ok, I didn't test it using Sybase. Is it possible that even in Sybase the fieldterminator has the need to be coherent between the data.txt file and the parameters on bulk insert?

Also found this [link] (http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00462.1510/concepts/con_sqlcode.html) and searched for "-131 bulk".